# How to compile neon on ARM

Tags: arm, cross-compiling, gnu

I used the

`arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ test.cpp -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -o test`

on ubantu to get an excecutable file on ARM, but when I ran

```
adb push ./test /data/test
adb shell
cd data
chmod 777 test
./test
```

I got the following error:

```
./system/bin/sh: ./test: No such file or directory
```

I was confused about this.

Comment: Anywhere different？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you intend to run the executable on Android (as it seems), you should ideally build it using the Android NDK. The problem is that your executable links to glibc which is available on normal linux systems, but not on Android. (In detail, the executable can't start because it requires the dynamic linker `/lib/ld-linux.so.3` which isn't available on Android. In addition, it also requires glibc in the form of `libc.so.6`.)

If you build executables using the Android NDK, it will link to the Bionic libc, which is what is available on Android.

Alternatively, if you add `-static` when linking (in your case, in your single compile+link command), you'll get a static executable, which should work on both normal linux and Android.

Comment: If the answer worked and answers your question, you should accept it as well.